# Send text to app (not specific phone number)

Tags: android, sms, broadcastreceiver, sendmessage

I don't know if this is even possible, couldn't find anything usefull on the internet.

I wanted to make an app, that me and some of my friends could send a message trough "my app" and that everyone who has that app, receive the message, without using a phone number.

So basically, same as WhatsApp GroupConversation, but then without using a phone number.
Is this even possible?

If it is possible, could you put me on the right track to start with.

Hope I am clear enough, if not, tell me :)

**Edit:**
This just pops up in my head (didn't look on internet yet), but what I want, is a kind of a shoutbox.

Comment: It is very possible, all you have to make is a chat server... Whatapp uses phonenumber as the identifying thing. It is not needed for the messages to be forwarded around.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible, in fact WhatsApp does not use your phone number for this at all.
You simply provide your phone number to asure a unique ID and proof that you are indeed in possession of this phone with the validation SMS.

From there on, your phone number isn't even used anymore.

You can go 2 ways with this;

1. Create a simple webservice with a database on which you just save and request messages. Maybe make a little difference between get all or get latest message. Anyone, hooking into the group, can just fetch the same data. With the use of GCM push notifications, you can make this pretty instant.
2. Use XMPP, which is a chat protocol kinda all the chats use. Whatsapp, Google talk, FB messenger... This will provide you with instant messaging just like any other chat app or program you know.

Option 2 is by far the best in final functionality, but be warned that XMPP is quite complex and error prone. 
You can look into the asmack and asmackx libraries for Android, which will give you the basic functionality with ease. Going a bit deeper, you'll have to dig into the protocol and really get to know it though.

ps. For both you'll need your own server, however with asmack(x) you are also allowed to use Google's  Talk servers for free. Communication will go through your Gmail account. Basically with this you just make your own version of Google Talk.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible by implementing server-client architecture. Your app will use a common database for all the users. whenever an user install your app, he will achieve an unique user ID. if anyone uninstall it, his id will be destroyed. You can track the users from those ID in database. You don't need phone numbers.